# Unsupported driver mysql illuminate

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using Illuminate with Slim v3. Trying to connect to database results in an error :

```
Type: InvalidArgumentException
Message: Unsupported driver []
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\slim-app\vendor\illuminate\database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory.php
Line: 237
```

My config is as follow :

```
$db_host = "127.0.0.1";
$db_name = "db";
$db_user = "user";
$db_pass = "password";


use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager AS Capsule;

$capsule = new Capsule();
$capsule->addConnection([
  'dirver'    => "mysql",
  "host"      => $db_host,
  "database"  => $db_name,
  "username"  => $db_user,
  "password"  => $db_pass,
  "charset"   => "utf8",
  "collation" => "utf8_general_ci",
  "prefix"    => ""
]);

$capsule->bootEloquent();
```

And trying to connect :

```
$_message = new Message();
$messages = $_message->all();
```

The error is occuring. Can somebody help me to fix it ?

Comment: You've got a typo - `dirver` -> `driver`

Comment: Oh yeah. Thanks, a lot.